# How to define and set a variable from a file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

I have two files `one.txt` and other `two.txt`.

one.txt file contents:

```
"21"
"22"
"23"
```

two.txt file contents:

```
"Hi how are you"
"Hello who are you"
"May I help you"
```

now I want to extract fist line of `one.txt` and append an "_"(underscore) at the beginning to make it a variable and then extract the first line of `two.txt` and assign it to the variable declared i.e, it should look like

```
_21="Hi how are you"
_22="Hello who are you"
_23="May i help you"
echo $_21     #This should print "Hi how are you"
```

The variable should be declared as above. Is it possible to do it using bash script?

Comment: are all those quotes actually in the files?

Comment: No i just wrote them to make them look like string

Comment: You should edit your question to remove them since they would just complicate the answers

Comment: yeah sorry about that, but i think i should keep them because couple of you already answerd it. Should i still edit it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using paste, like @αғsнιη's answer, but a little simpler processing

```bsh
while IFS=$'\t' read num value; do
  declare "_$num=$value"
done < <(paste {one,two}.txt)
```

then

```bsh
$ echo "$_21"
Hi how are you

$ echo "$_22"
Hello who are you

$ echo "$_23"
May I help you
```

Answer (score 1):

```
eval "$(paste -d"_=''" /dev/null <(tr -d \" <one) /dev/null two /dev/null)"
```

`paste` the files/input with `-d="..."` delimiters defined in the list.

we used `/dev/null` as a dummy input in order to generate the first `_` and put the second file `two` contents inside a single quote to avoid expand each if they were contains variables, command substitution; like for the input below:

one.txt:

```
"21"
"22"
"23"
```

---

two.txt:

```
"Hi $(date) how are you"
"Hello who are you"
"May I help you"
```

Output is:

```
_21='"Hi $(date) how are you"'
_22='"Hello who are you"'
_23='"May I help you"'
```

---

```
$ echo "${_21}"
"Hi $(date) how are you"
```

if you want them expand before they get assign to related variables, so change the command to:

```
$ eval "$(paste -d"_=" /dev/null <(tr -d \" <one) two )"
$ echo "${_21}"
Hi Tue 24 Nov 2020 12:47:40 AM +0330 how are you
```

Comment: Hi αғsнιη thanks for the answer, it is working can you please explain how this is working. And sorry regarding accepting the answer i can only accept one and i understood another answer as soon as i see it. Can you explain how this script which you wrote is working.